# Adding FEMA Hazard WMS Layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to add a FEMA Hazard WMS layer to QGIS. I am using QGIS version 3.4.11-Madeira. I have used a shapefile in the past, but the hope with the WMS is that it would auto-update.

I went to https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/wps/portal/NFHLWMS and copied the url https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHLWMS/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Then I clicked add new layer, WMS, new, I pasted the URL WMS url above and clicked connect. I get the following response.

> The server you are trying to connect to does not seem to be a WMS server. Please check the URL.
>
> Instead of the capabilities string that was expected, the following response has been received:Could not get WMS capabilities: error occurred while parsing reference at line 86 column 118
>
> This is probably due to an incorrect WMS Server URL.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am using QGIS version 3.4.11-Madeira

Comment: works when you use ArcGISMapServer connection rather than WMS/WMTS connection

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error messages when trying to connect to the WMS server, but I was able to connect to the data by two other methods:

1. Use the links provided under the header, "ArcGIS REST Service," to add an ArcGIS Map Server connection.

   - NFHL (effective data only): https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer
   - Preliminary NFHL: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/PrelimPending/Prelim_NFHL/MapServer
   - Pending NFHL: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/PrelimPending/Pending_NFHL/MapServer

   [image]
2. Use the link for OGC Web Feature Service (WFS) to connect to a WFS server.

   - https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/WFSServer

   [image]

Comment: I used the ArcGIS REST Service and it worked! Thanks for the help.